# What to do with this strange question?

Tags: discussion

I looked in chat but it was empty and had been for 2 days, and this was too hard to explain in a custom flag so...

See the post on main: https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/as-a-freelance-web-developer-what-could-you-do-with-a-x-budget

Call me paranoid or a skeptic, but this reads like a market research questionnaire posing as a legitimate question.

Consider the information being asked for

- Link to something you worked on (identifies the user with a project)
- What do you think it was worth to your client? (find out what others are charging)
- Where do you live? (which countries have the cheapest freelancers).

Answer (score 4):

I agree; it feels like a survey of some kind, but the more compelling reason to close it is that it's way too broad in the first place.

I've closed the question and notified the OP that they should edit their question to be more specific.